# Subgroup in $S_6$ which contains the $6$-cycle $(123456)$?

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I am practicing some elementary problems on group theory

the question is; Find the smallest subgroup $S$ of $S_6$ containing the $6-$cycle $(123456)$ [list all elements of $S_6$ cyclic notation]

I think that if $(123456)$ is in $S$ then it's inverse $(165432)$ should be in $S$ and all permutations which generated by $(123456)$ should be in $S$ $(135)(246), (14)(25)(36), (153)(264)$ is this right? is there any other proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly right. In any case, to find the smallest subgroup containing a single element, you simply take all the powers of that element. It will be a finite group if and only if some power of the element is equal to the identity.

To prove that the powers of $x$ are the smallest subgroup containing $x$, first it is clear that any subgroup that contains $x$ must also contain all powers of $x$. Conversely, all powers (both positive and negative) or $x$ form a subgroup. So we have shown that both sides are included in the other, and so they must be equal.

Comment: if the order of that element is infinite can we apply the same method?

Comment: @PrabathHewasundara Yes.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, the smallest subgroup of $S_6$ containing $\sigma = (123456)$ is the subgroup generated by $\sigma$.

$$< \sigma > = \{\sigma^n, \quad n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$$